# Azure SQL DWH Date Partitioning

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-partitioning, azure-synapse

Just keen to see a working example of how to partition a large table of (150 million rows with 30 columns), what are the best practices to partition such a big table by date (sample code please) 
Also, want to know how are these partitions are merged, switched out, and archived. Any TSQL code based implementation example is much appreciated.

Comment: You're more likely to get a answer if you do some research yourself about this topic and ask a specific question. All of the answers to your questions are basically links that you can google

Comment: I suggest you start by reviewing the examples in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql#examples-includesssdwfullincludessssdwfull-mdmd-and-includesspdwincludessspdw-mdmd) and ask more specific questions if you need further help. Your question is to broad as it stands.

Comment: I wouldn't partition a table at 150 million records. keep in mind you already have 60 distributions so it is effectively already partitioned. you want to keep your distribution size at around 1 million rows or higher to get effective column store compression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below how you partition a table by a date field:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactInternetSales]
(
    [ProductKey]            int          NOT NULL
,   [OrderDateKey]          int          NOT NULL
,   [CustomerKey]           int          NOT NULL
,   [PromotionKey]          int          NOT NULL
,   [SalesOrderNumber]      nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
,   [OrderQuantity]         smallint     NOT NULL
,   [UnitPrice]             money        NOT NULL
,   [SalesAmount]           money        NOT NULL
)
WITH
(   CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
,   DISTRIBUTION = HASH([ProductKey])
,   PARTITION   (   [OrderDateKey] RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES
                    (20000101,20010101,20020101
                    ,20030101,20040101,20050101
                    )
                )
)
;
```

Below is a sample partitioned columnstore table containing one row in each partition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactInternetSales]
(
        [ProductKey]            int          NOT NULL
    ,   [OrderDateKey]          int          NOT NULL
    ,   [CustomerKey]           int          NOT NULL
    ,   [PromotionKey]          int          NOT NULL
    ,   [SalesOrderNumber]      nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
    ,   [OrderQuantity]         smallint     NOT NULL
    ,   [UnitPrice]             money        NOT NULL
    ,   [SalesAmount]           money        NOT NULL
)
WITH
(   CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
,   DISTRIBUTION = HASH([ProductKey])
,   PARTITION   (   [OrderDateKey] RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES
                    (20000101
                    )
                )
)
;

INSERT INTO dbo.FactInternetSales
VALUES (1,19990101,1,1,1,1,1,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.FactInternetSales
VALUES (1,20000101,1,1,1,1,1,1);


CREATE STATISTICS Stat_dbo_FactInternetSales_OrderDateKey ON dbo.FactInternetSales(OrderDateKey);
```

SQL Data Warehouse supports partition splitting, merging, and switching. Each of these functions is excuted using the ALTER TABLE statement.

To create a partitioned table on Azure SQL Data Warehouse from data coming from another table, you can use CTAS as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FactInternetSales_20000101
    WITH    (   DISTRIBUTION = HASH(ProductKey)
            ,   CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
            ,   PARTITION   (   [OrderDateKey] RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES
                                (20000101
                                )
                            )
            )
AS
SELECT *
FROM    FactInternetSales
WHERE   1=2
;
```

For more information, please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-partition) documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Alberto. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-distribute